# Can the projective line be provided with a ring structure?

Tags: projective-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

A definition of multiplication on the projective $1$-points $(a:b)$ of $P_K^1$ with $a$ and $b$ elements of a field $K$ ( e.g. the real or rational numbers ) can be given by mimicking the multiplication of complex numbers.

Is it known whether there a way to define an addition between projective $1$-points ?

Comment: Your proposed multiplication isn't well-defined if $K$ itself already contains a square root of $-1$: in this case, $K[i]$ has zero divisors, so it's possible for the "product" of two points to have both coordinates zero and hence to not be a well-defined point on the projective line.

Comment: If $K$ doesn't contain a square root of $-1$, then your group is the quotient of the multiplicative group of $K[i]$ by the multiplicative group of $K$. The closest ring in sight is $K[i]$, which, being a field, has no nontrivial quotients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The topological space $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a circle, so it has an abelian group structure just defined by adding angles but this is not algebraic, not compatible with the multiplication you describe, and it can't be extended to $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ (which is a sphere and thus has no topological group structure), nor does it restrict to $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$. **EDIT**: As Noam Elkies points out,  the circle group structure can be made algebraic on $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ by defining it by $\tan(x+y)=\tan(x)+\tan(y)$, instead of by adding angles.  This still has all the other defects listed above.

More generally, it's impossible to do this algebraically: it's an extremely well known fact that a projective curve with an algebraic group structure (as addition would be) must be an elliptic curve.

Comment: It is far beyond my knowledge that "a projective curve with an algebraic group structure (as addition would be) must be an elliptic curve". In what kind of books do I find this remarkable result ? Algebraic Geometry, Elliptic Curves, or Projective Geometry ?

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann You can find the case for $K = \mathbb{C}$ here on page 10: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf

You should probably read the earlier pages to see how he defines an abelian variety.

The general case for other fields $K$ should follow from either the Lefschetz principle when $char(K) = 0$ or by (trivial) deformation theory when $char(K) > 0$ by lifting to characteristic 0.

Comment: Actually there *is* an algebraic group structure on ${\bf P}^1_{\bf R}$,
namely $x \oplus y = (x+y) \, / \, (1-xy)$.  But it can't extend to
 ${\bf P}^1_{\bf C}$, nor to a ring structure on ${\bf P}^1_{\bf R}$.

Comment: This looks like the addition formula of the $\tan$-function.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: Yes, it is obtained by conjugating addition on $\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Z}$ by the homeomorphism $\tan:\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Sorry - I dont understand what "conjugating addition" means.

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line I see under section "Line extended by a point at infinity" some formulas for addition and multiplication - alas no citation of the source of these rules.

Comment: If $\phi: X \to Y$ is a bijection and $X$ carries a group structure (denoted by $+_X$), then $Y$ carries a group structure by "conjugation": $y +_Y y' = \phi(\phi^{-1}(y) +_X \phi^{-1}(y'))$. This I'm sure is what Eric meant. Another term for this (which generalizes to any sort of structure you like) is "transport of structure". It's a general thing all mathematicians pick up on at some point.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: Notice that the formulas on the Wikipedia page are only partially defined: $0 \cdot \infty$ and $\infty + \infty$ are undefined. So this does not make $\mathbf{P}^1_K$ into a ring.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a less algebraic and more topological answer: it's known that any compact (Hausdorff) topological ring [must be totally disconnected](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/08/holy_crap_do_you_know_what_a_c.html). In particular, there's no hope for either $\mathbb{RP}^1$ or $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to have the structure of a topological ring. (As Ben Webster mentions, $\mathbb{CP}^1$ also can't even be a topological group.)